# What tool to use to view an object file?

Tags: utilities, binutils

I'm reading an old book on linkers and loaders and it has images of object code.

But I can't figure out what tools are used to display the contents of these files.

I'd appreciate if someone could point out the tool.

Here is the C code and corresponding display of the object files.

Source file `m.c`:

```
extern void a(char *);

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  static char string[] = "Hello, world!\n";
  a(string);
}
```

Source file `a.c`:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>

void a(char *s)
{
  write(1, s, strlen(s));
}
```

Object code for `m.o`:

```
Sections:
Idx Name Size VMA LMA File off Algn
0 .text 00000010 00000000 00000000 00000020 2**3
1 .data 00000010 00000010 00000010 00000030 2**3
Disassembly of section .text: 00000000 <_main>:
0: 55 pushl %ebp
1: 89 e5 movl %esp,%ebp
3: 68 10 00 00 00 pushl $0x10
4: 32 .data
8: e8 f3 ff ff ff call 0
9: DISP32 _a
d: c9 leave
e: c3 ret
...
```

Object code for `a.o`:

```
Sections:
Idx Name Size VMA LMA File off Algn
0 .text 0000001c 00000000 00000000 00000020 2**2
CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, RELOC, CODE
1 .data 00000000 0000001c 0000001c 0000003c 2**2
CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, DATA
Disassembly of section .text: 00000000 <_a>:
0: 55 pushl %ebp
1: 89 e5 movl %esp,%ebp
3: 53 pushl %ebx
4: 8b 5d 08 movl 0x8(%ebp),%ebx
7: 53 pushl %ebx
8: e8 f3 ff ff ff call 0
9: DISP32 _strlen
d: 50 pushl %eax
e: 53 pushl %ebx
f: 6a 01 pushl $0x1
11: e8 ea ff ff ff call 0
12: DISP32 _write
16: 8d 65 fc leal -4(%ebp),%esp
19: 5b popl %ebx
1a: c9 leave
1b: c3 ret
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use `objdump`. See [man objdump](http://linux.die.net/man/1/objdump). For example `-d` option for disassemble (there are a lot of options):

```
objdump -d a.o
```

Another useful programs are included in [binutils](https://sourceware.org/binutils/).

Answer (score 1):

See objdump options. For example:

objdump -d a.o

objdump -D a.o

objdump -S a.o

[image]

Comment: Don't post images of text.